# the norm of a state on the full matrix

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $M$ be a 2 by 2 full matrix. $\phi$ is a state on $M$ with density $(\beta, 1-\beta)$, then we can find only one projection $e\in M$ with $\|\phi_{eM(1-e)}\|=|1-2\beta|$.

How to choose the projection $e$?

Comment: You should try out some examples. E.g., try of $\beta = \frac{1}{2}$ (so that you just get the normalized trace), and try to come up with a projection $e$. Then try another $\beta$ and see if you can generalize this.

Comment: Also, you say you can only choose one projection $e$. If you try out the $\beta = \frac{1}{2}$ example, there are at least 2 $e$s which work (once you find $e$, $1 - e$ will also work.).

Comment: Do you mean that we can take $\phi=\left [ \begin{matrix}
     \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 &   \frac{1}{2} \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$

Comment: In that case, $\phi$ would a matrix, not a state. What do you mean by density? My understanding was $\phi(A) = \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}\left(\begin{pmatrix} \beta & 0 \\ 0 & 1 - \beta\end{pmatrix}A\right)$.